# Static IP received from ISP, want to assign it to my OpenBSD VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, static-ip, openbsd

I have a virtual machine setup with OpenBSD that I am using to for playing around with and I wanted to assign one of the static IPs from the block I received from Comcast to the machine.

I have a static internal IP of 10.1.10.208 assigned to the VM which works flawlessly, I can ssh and do whatever kind of connects from inside my network just fine. The connection provided by VirtualBox is in Bridged mode.

I can't seem to find much on the web for assigning an external IP to OpenBSD. On the host of the OpenBSD VM I run Linux Mint, and that was relatively simple. I opened the network preferences and added a new route with a new gateway and everything along side my internal route and it worked right away. This doesn't seem as simple with OpenBSD.

The hostname for the machine is to be: rigby.4lambda.net
The subnet is 255.255.255.248

Any assistance or pointers in the right direction would be phenomenal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an **external (global) IP address** to an **internal (private) IP address**, you need NAT (Network Address Translation). In a regular setting where only 1 IP address is available, this would turn an internal address to a port on the external address. IE:

```
192.168.1.3 --> 132.68.51.43:69256
192.168.1.4 --> 132.68.51.43:57842
192.168.1.5 --> 132.68.51.43:58366
```

This is **Dynamic NAT**, as the ports are mapped to traffic automatically by the router. There is also **Static NAT**, where a single internal IP address is manually mapped to a single external IP address, IE:

```
192.168.1.3 --> 195.67.241.7 (Static IP given by ISP)
```

This sounds like what you're after.

The place to set this up would be wherever your NAT is done, this is usually the gateway router to the internet. You can leave your OpenBSD with its internal ip address as the address swapping will be done at the gateway router.

Comment: I understand, I appreciate your reply! Unfortunately Comcast does not give these options in their business gateways (at least not my model). I found a different solution instead which I will post. However your post was a direct answer to my question where as what I did was a clever work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround but have marked another posters post as the answer since it is related to the question I posted.

My motherboard has two ports on it. I configured my VM as bridged with both of my ethernet jacks.

One of the jacks identifies both the VM and my host on the LAN with local IPs. The other ethernet jack identifies the VM and the host to the world with Static IPs. This way I am no longer stacking Internal and External on one link anymore and have divvied them up.

I prefer this as I am not able to have separate config files for internal communications and external.